# dpkg cannot remove package > linux-restricted-modules

Tags: kernel, dpkg

I'm having a couple of issues with my Ubuntu server currently. When using apt for anything it tells me:

```
The following packages will be REMOVED
    linux-restricted-modules-2.6.28-11-server 
    linux-restricted-modules-2.6.28-19-server
```

But the uninstall fails because the directories and images already do not exist.

```
dkpg --list | grep linux-restricted-modules
```

...returns this information:

```
rH  linux-restricted-modules-2.6.28-11-server 2.6.28-11.15   
rH  linux-restricted-modules-2.6.28-19-server 2.6.28-19.24
```

So the r means I want it removed and I think the H means it only half exists on the system or something?

How to I remove whatever is left of this package so I can stop receiving these error messages?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**
Complete output of apt-get upgrade:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED
  linux-restricted-modules-2.6.28-11-server linux-restricted-modules-2.6.28-19-server
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 5,046kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 59849 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-restricted-modules-2.6.28-11-server ...
rmdir: failed to remove `/lib/modules/2.6.28-11-server/volatile/': No such file or     directory
FATAL: Could not open '/boot/System.map-2.6.28-11-server': No such file or directory
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-2.6.28-11-server
Cannot find /lib/modules/2.6.28-11-server
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-2.6.28-11-server
dpkg: error processing linux-restricted-modules-2.6.28-11-server (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Removing linux-restricted-modules-2.6.28-19-server ...
rmdir: failed to remove `/lib/modules/2.6.28-19-server/volatile/': No such file or     directory
FATAL: Could not open '/boot/System.map-2.6.28-19-server': No such file or directory
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-2.6.28-19-server
Cannot find /lib/modules/2.6.28-19-server
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-2.6.28-19-server
dpkg: error processing linux-restricted-modules-2.6.28-19-server (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-restricted-modules-2.6.28-11-server
 linux-restricted-modules-2.6.28-19-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Have a look at the `/var/log/apt/term.log` (as root) and try to find a reference to the packages. There should be a message why the remove operation failed.

Comment: It basically states that the directories associated do not exist. I'll update my question with the complete output.

Comment: Please try to find the original (oldest) failed attempt.

Comment: It first occurred when upgrading from Karmic to Lucid (current). The error message is the same as the above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Find the `/var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-restricted-modules-2.6.28-11-server.postrm` file and move it somewhere else, for example

```
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-restricted-modules-2.6.28-11-server.postrm /var/tmp
```

Then run the `apt-get upgrade` again. If that works, do the same to the other package.

This is not the best way of doing this, but it should work. The `postrm` script is failing, because you no longer have the kernel `2.6.28-11-server` installed.

Comment: This seemed to have the desired effect! Thank you sir!